# Non-CP routes in plugins

Tags: plugin-development, routes

I'm building a custom plugin and need to have a publicly accessible (non-CP) route as part of the plugin.

From what I've read I can use `registerSiteRoutes()` to register non-CP routes within my plugin. However, I'm getting a 404 when I do this. Here's my setup.

**MyPlugin.php**

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

  class MyPlugin extends BasePlugin {

    ...

    public function registerSiteRoutes() {
      return array(
        'myroute'           => array('action' => 'myplugin/access/index')
      );
    }
  }
```

**MyPlugin_AccessController.php**

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class Portal_AccessController extends BaseController {

  protected $allowAnonymous = true;

  public function index() {

    $templatesPath = craft()->path->pluginsPath().'myplugin/templates/site/';
    craft()->path->setTemplatesPath($templatesPath);

    $this->renderTemplate('index');

  }

}
```

I have setup a basic template at `/plugins/myplugin/templates/site/index.html`

Hitting `mydomain.com/myplugin` results in a 404. Am I thinking of this correctly? Is it possible to have a non-CP route that points to a controller method in my plugin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here:

1. Any action methods in the controller class needs the "action" prefix to their name, i.e. `actionIndex()` for your "index" action, or `actionLogin()` for another action route calling "myPlugin/access/login".

In other words, rename your `index()` method in the controller to `actionIndex()`, and it should work.

2. For action routes, plugin handles should be written in camelcase – i.e. "**myPlugin**/access/index", not "**myplugin**/access/index".
3. You have a minor typo in the controller:

   $templatesPath = craft()->path->**pluginsPath()**.'myplugin/templates/site/';

should read

```
$templatesPath = craft()->path->getPluginsPath().'myplugin/templates/site/';
```

*Addendum: this might just be a typo in the question text, but your controller class is actually named* "Portal_AccessController"*, so it will obviously not respond to the route "myPlugin/access/index" – the latter should read "portal/access/index" (or the controller should be renamed "MyPlugin_AccessController)*

Comment: Not sure why this thing not working for me and keeps giving `Unable to resolve the request`